# Matching complex patterns with intent filters and data

Tags: android

My intent filter looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite" android:pathPattern="/oauth/authorize?.*oauth_verifier=.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

however this fails to match.

If I remove the **?** and everything after it, it matches but the site I am matching uses that URL several times, and the only one I am interested in is the oauth_verifier.

Is there anyway to make an intent filter match the bit (query parameters?) after the */oauth/authorize*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to make an intent filter match the bit (query parameters?) after the /oauth/authorize

No, sorry.